# How to insert multiple arrays without using foreach in Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, insert

Hi friends i have this array:

```
let array = [
    {name:"a",age"b",id:1},
    {name:"a",age"b",id:1},
    {name:"a",age"b",id:1},
]
```

for insert the data in firebase i use this:

```
const saveItem = list => ref.child("story").push(list);

array.forEach(element => saveItem(element));
```

Is posibble insert without the `forEeach` ? (something like bulk in Mongo.)

```
saveItem(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
  firebase.database().ref('story').push({
    name: "a",
    age: "20",
    id : "1"
  });
```

I'am assuming here that each user is entering there name, age and then clicking submit, in this case you have the following database:

```
story
   randomId
       name : a
       age : 20
       id  : 1
   randomId
       name : b
       age : 10
       id : 2
```